# Search string in prepared statement

Tags: java, mysql

I'm working on a database including data about phonetic symbols.
When I use prepared statement to search for a symbol like this:

```
    String sql="select pic from picture where symbol=?";
    PreparedStatement ps=null;
    try{
            ps=c.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1,str); //str is a symbol of a pronunciation
            rs=ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                is=rs.getBinaryStream("pic");
              ImageUtil.readBlob(is,"C:\\Users\\HarryTao\\Desktop\\1\\"+String.valueOf(i)+"(1).jpg");
            }
        }
```

When the program is run, the pictures stored in the database can't be stored on my computer, and no errors or warnings occur.

I tried to add `\"` before and after the question mark in ps but it didn't work.

I have no idea where the problem is. If I change the `sql` string to search by the id of the elements, it works well.

```
    String sql="select front from picture where picture_id=?";
    ...
    ps.setInt(1,1);
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my string operation?

Comment: I'd like to see how the `symbol` column is defined and the data type for `str`

Comment: if the data type for symbol is String (Text) then perhaps you should try enclosing the the supplied data with apostrophes:  String sql="select pic from picture where symbol='" + ? + "'";

Comment: Do you have a catch block? Maybe you are just ignoring it and seem what seems to be working but it isn't

Comment: symbol is defined as varchar and str is string type

Answer (score 0):

Escape util method will help you

[enter link description here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html)

```
enter code hereString sql="select pic from picture where symbol=?";
PreparedStatement ps=null;
try{
        ps=c.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1,StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql(str)); //str is a symbol of a pronunciation
        rs=ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            is=rs.getBinaryStream("pic");
          ImageUtil.readBlob(is,"C:\\Users\\HarryTao\\Desktop\\1\\"+String.valueOf(i)+"(1).jpg");
        }
    }
```